# Error when getting information for file - Input/output error

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive, backup, rsync

I ran rsync `sudo rsync -aE --progress /mnt/seagate/dataset/RD\ 8* /mnt/backUp/backUp/dataset/` and pressed `ctrl-c` by mistake. There was a SIG-INT error whic makes sense. 
But now, I am not able to access the hard disk mounted on `/mnt/backUp`.

Whenver I try to access my drive, it says:
**This location could not be displayed. Sorry, could not display all the contents of “dataset”: Error when getting information for file '/mnt/backUp/backUp/dataset/RD 838Jun05': Input/output error**

output of `sudo ll` is attached in the image below.
[output sudo ll](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BEE1T.png)

I tried running :
`sudo smartctl -i /dev/sde2` whose output is

```
smartctl 6.2 2013-07-26 r3841 [x86_64-linux-4.2.0-42-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-13, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Vendor:               Seagate
Product:              BUP BK
Revision:             0108
User Capacity:        4,000,787,029,504 bytes [4.00 TB]
Logical block size:   512 bytes
Physical block size:  4096 bytes
Lowest aligned LBA:   0
Logical block provisioning type unreported, LBPME=0, LBPRZ=0
Logical Unit id:      0x3e41375436453851
Serial number:        NA7T6E8Q
Device type:          disk
Local Time is:        Sun Aug  6 16:55:06 2017 EDT
SMART support is:     Unavailable - device lacks SMART capability.
```

I am still able to move the files that were already existing though, which I am assuming, means that only few sectors went bad.
Can you please tell me if there is any way I could fix this? I am not able to do `ntfs-fix` as well

Answer (score 0):

`Input/output error` is bad news in general. It means that the drive is faulty and is unable to read and/or write data from/to the spinning plates.

If this is a new drive I and is still under warranty I suggest you return it and get a new one.

You may try command `dmesg` immediately after you get that I/O error and you will see a lot of kernel mumbo-jumbo about how it is unable to use the device. Not very helpful to the regular user but I am sure some kernel developer is in a position to understand it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am still able to move the unbroken files though, which I am assuming, means that only few sectors went bad.  Is there any way I could fix them?

Comment: If your drive is formatted ntfs you might be better off attaching it to a Windows PC and let it do a full scan. There is a utility `badbclocks` which integrates nicely with Ext2/3/4 filesystems but I don't think it would be much of a help for you. Regardless, I wouldn't trust that drive.